# How to change and suppress some of the field key names in JSON result?

Tags: php

I am getting json result from api using curl. Result is like this

```
{
Count: 2,
Message: "Results returned successfully",
Results: [
{
myDescription: "test",
myid: 9403
},
{
myDescription: "test2",
myId: 9408
}}]}
```

I need to suppress the "Message" and change "myDescription" to "Description" how I can do that ?

Comment: Try using "json_decode()" to convert it to an array (check the manual for creating an Array vs. an Object). Modify the array ($a['Results']['Description'] = $a['Results']['myDescription']; unset($a['Results']['myDescription'];), then convert it back with json_encode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid json:

```
{
   "Count":2,
   "Message":"Results returned successfully",
   "Results":[
      {
         "myDescription":"test",
         "myId":9403
      },
      {
         "myDescription":"test2",
         "myId":9408
      }
   ]
}
```

Php code:

```
<?php
    $jsondata = json_decode($json, true);//$json - your json string
    unset($jsondata["Message"]);
    foreach($jsondata["Results"] as $key => $result)
    {
        $jsondata["Results"][$key]['Description'] = $result['myDescription'];
        unset($jsondata["Results"][$key]['myDescription']);
    }

    $json_new = json_encode($jsondata);//if you want to remake the json
```